# Almost Duplicate Description but different images, internal links and meta title and description

Tags: seo, googlebot, duplicate-content, ranking, pagerank

I am creating a real estate website and I have thousands of property pages in the similar location.

For the property in the same locations, the property descriptions are almost similar like as follows (XYZ defines the word which is different)-

XYZ is ........(100 words)....XYZ...(50 words).....XYZ......(100 words)

This is the format I have followed for all property descriptions. The images, meta title, meta description and internal links are different though. I want to know if this practice would have any considerable negative amount of my rankings ?

Answer (score 1):

For on-page copy, I would introduced some more points of variability. Try to have each sentence be slightly unique.

Comment: I understand that would be the ideal scenario but I have thousands of properties and it is not poossible to setup unique descriptions for all of them. The only thing I can do is setup a variable to replace the property title into description at 3-4 places (so to even avoid keyword stuffing)

Do you think I should be worried about the impact of duplication much when I got everything else like - Title, meta description, meta title, images and internal links - these are unique for all listings.

Comment: Possibly. Try testing it out with having Google crawl 40 or so of these property pages (or artificial ones) and see what happens. If you can, introduce some other source of textual variability on the pages, e.g. headline, property details, etc.

Comment: That isn't enough variation to have each page indexed Google.  Rather than trying to get 1000 pages indexed, spend more time on ten or even fifty of them and get a few of them indexed.    Google won't penalize your whole site for having a bunch of duplication, just the pages that have such thin content.  As you take the time to add more to any page, it will get indexed.

Comment: Headline, Property Details, Images, Meta Title, Meta Description and are ALL different. 

The only place where duplication exists is Property description (200 words approx). I do not know how much I should care for it.

I would try with some demo pages to see the effect though, though I believe in the new changes google confirmed there is no penalty for duplication just more preference to unique content.